# How can I project a time series out to the present day in Quiver Analysis?

Tags: time-series, palantir-foundry

I have a Quiver Analysis page containing many time series. I build these time series using functions combining other time series data and variables. One of the time series does not update it’s information that frequently, however I want the graph to project all the way to the current day. How can I do that?

[image: Time Series that ends at last updated]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the interpolation settings on all of the component time series are set so that the "after" category is `nearest` instead of `None`

[image: editor page showing interpolations]

Remember to also set the interpolation  settings for any variables that this time series is based off of.

[image: editor page for variable]